# Push Pop Press style Scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, scroll

I am working on a app that requires scrolling implemented in Our Choice iPad app from Push Pop Press.
Has anyone implemented the nested scrolling like that?

Updated:

There are two scroll views, one on top with paging and another at the bottom. The top one specifies the Chapters and bottom one corresponds to the pages in the chapter.

So when you swipe to next page of top scroller the bottom one moves accordingly to show it pages. And you can scroll bottom scrollview to view the pages on it. Also when you are at the last few pages of the bottom scroll view and try to scroll then it changes the page at the top scroll view and update the bottom scroll view as well.

Here is the demo video of the app

http://vimeo.com/22872218

Comment: Can you describe the scrolling behavior more precisely? A lot of potential answerers won't know/want to download that app, no matter how cool the scrolling may be :)

Comment: Tim, I have updated the comment with more description. Thanks for the advice.